# Constructor overloads and class parameters

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

Is there a better way to do what I am doing:

```
class Sample {

int SampleValueX, SampleValueY;
string SampleFacing;    

public Sample(int samplevaluex, string samplefacing)
{
    SampleValueX = startpositionx;
    SampleValueY = 0;
    SampleFacing = samplefacing;
}

public Sample(int samplevaluey, string samplefacing)
{
    SampleValueX = 0;
    SampleValueY = startpositionx;
    SampleFacing = samplefacing;
}
}
```

Is this even known as constructor overloading? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: When you have the same order of parameters' type on a method (or ctor) it will not allow you compile.

Comment: ough... same constructor (parameter types) but different logic? better use static functions with apropriete names (createX, createYSample) and giving the constructor the power to set all 3 members

Comment: The signatures need to be different, what you have will not work since your signature is Sample(int, string) for both

Comment: @Najzero can you expand on giving the constructor the power to set all 3 members?

Comment: @Anicho see levelnis answer. When you instantiate an object simply pass the value (x/y or both) you wish for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use optional parameters

```
class Sample {

  int SampleValueX, SampleValueY;
  string SampleFacing;    

  public Sample(string samplefacing, int samplevaluex = 0, int samplevaluey = 0)
  {
    SampleValueX = samplevaluex;
    SampleValueY = samplevaluey;
    SampleFacing = samplefacing;
  }

}
```

Note that the optional parameters must appear after the mandatory ones

Comment: Thank you @levelnis this is exactly what I am after. So by setting a default value in the arguments makes them optional.

Answer (score 4):

This could not work because you have two constructor with the same parameters and inside the constructor you can't differentiate between one form to the other.

With Visual Studio 2008 and subsequent versions you can initialize your objects with the [object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx)

```
    Sample sampleInstance = new Sample
    {
        SampleValueX = 0,
        SampleValueY = 10,
        SampleFacing = "MySample"
    };
```

This will remove the need to initialize your internal members.
Of course this requires that your internal properties becomes public and this is not always the case.

```
class Sample
{
    public int SampleValueX {get;set;};
    public int SampleValueY {get;set;};
    public string SampleFacing {get; set;};

    ......
```

Comment: This is also dangerous as you can have constructed objects lacking essential information if the properties have not been set.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion this kind of logic does not adds value to the class. If the class has 3 parameters and you want to set them from the constructor I would add a constructor with the 3 parameters and set to 0 the required one on the constructor call.

That way would be clearer for the class user what the class parameter values are.

Comment: optional parameters seems like the answer @SoMoS thanks for info

Answer (score 2):

I agree that optional parameters is probably what you want here. An alternative could be:

```
class Sample
{
    int SampleValueX,  SampleValueY;
    string SampleFacing;

    public Sample(XSetting xSetting)
    {
        SampleValueX = xSetting.X;
        SampleValueY = 0;
        SampleFacing = xSetting.SampleFacing;
    }

    public Sample(YSetting ySetting)
    {
        SampleValueX = 0;
        SampleValueY = ySetting.Y;
        SampleFacing = ySetting.SampleFacing;
    }
}

public class XSetting
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public string SampleFacing { get; set; }
}

public class YSetting
{
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public string SampleFacing { get; set; }
}
```

As your code example looks this is probably overkill.

Your code example will not compile btw.

Comment: thank you great example. Optional parameters is exactly what I am after. The above is good for more complex cases.